# operating lists

Tags: list-manipulation

I have 2 lists 25 items, as I do so that data entering this formula

```
d = {1, 0, 2, 1, 3, 0, 2, 4, 1, 3, 0, 5, 2, 4, 1, 6, 3, 0, 5, 2, 7, 4,
1, 6, 3};
t = {0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 3, 0, 2, 1, 3, 0, 2, 4, 1, 3, 0, 2,
4, 1, 3};
po[d_, t_] := Binomial[14, d] Binomial[14 - d, t]
```

How do I get a table of 25 results numbered on the left?

something

```
1) Output 1
2) Output 2
3) Output 3
..

25) Output 25
```

Comment: Look up `Grid` in the documentation.

Comment: Perhaps you could use Table to get your table, you just need to think what to ask Table to generate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
d = {1, 0, 2, 1, 3, 0, 2, 4, 1, 3, 0, 5, 2, 4, 1, 6, 3, 0, 5, 2, 7, 4,
    1, 6, 3};
t = {0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 3, 0, 2, 1, 3, 0, 2, 4, 1, 3, 0, 2,
    4, 1, 3};
po[d_, t_] := Binomial[14, d] Binomial[14 - d, t];

Grid[{First[#], po @@ Rest[#]} & /@ 
  Transpose[{Range[Length[d]], d, t}]]
```

[image]

Alternatively, make the function `po` `Listable`

```
SetAttributes[po, Listable];
```

Then just use

```
Transpose[{Range[Length[d]], po[d, t]}] // Grid
```

Comment: thanks, works !!
     Grid[{First[#], po @@ Rest[#]} & /@ 
  Transpose[{Range[Length[d]], d, t}]]   You can explain ?

Comment: Look at the documentation for the various functions/operators. `Transpose[{Range[Length[d]], d, t}]]` forms a list of triplets. The pure function `{First[#], po @@ Rest[#]} &` is mapped onto the triplets to extract the first element and apply the function `po` to the last two elements of the triplet. `Grid` just displays the output as a table.